What is this video technique called and is there software to automate it?
First time question on this stack
I'm trying to make videos for social media, but find it is incredibly time consuming, I'd like to turn long shots into short snippets that skip to the important bits though (a) I'm not sure what that is called, and (b) if there is a software that can do it and if not (c) is there a tutorial to simplify it?
I have put some examples before, it's quite common in cooking videos or 'satisfying' cleaning videos
Cooking
A https://www.instagram.com/reel/C6RKtZFRZcb/?igsh=eGx2c293djF4MThr
B https://www.instagram.com/reel/C3deIhZOSbn/?igsh=NnZhYWhlcXV2bXdj
Cleaning
A https://www.instagram.com/reel/C6ZDywYoXWp/?igsh=Y21hMWp1bTg3YnBr
B https://www.instagram.com/reel/C409ZbWoyCd/?igsh=MTE2N3QxYjM4aTY2dw==
It's often used for crafting and DIY too
But effectively I have long videos of me doing something that I want to jump cut to be 30 seconds or so just of the main/interesting bits but want to know if this can be automated or if you need to go through and choose c.2-5 second chunks
Thanks in advance,

This technique is called jump-cutting, and while it isn't easily automated it can be done pretty quickly with keyboard shortcuts and pro editing software.
In Premiere Pro, for example:

Scrub through the timeline. Every time you get to a moment you want, use the razor tool to cut the clip (ctrl+k), skip a few frames, and make another cut. Repeat.
Once you've made all your cuts, select every clip and ripple delete (shift+delete) them.

This is also possible in other (free) editing software, such as DaVinci Resolve, but keybindings may be different. A similar process can be used, though.

Thanks Cam, are there any recommended free video editors for this?

DaVinci Resolve is a great option! It has the same/similar features, but the key combinations may be different. It's an incredibly powerful free video editor, I just suggested Premiere because I'm most familiar with it.
